# Does increasing the FEC decreases the payload in the maximum packet size?

Tags: packet-analysis, mtu, packet-loss, ber

we can find the maximum packet size by the formula

packet err rate = 1 - (1 - bit err rate)^(max packet size)

so does this max packet size include the FEC bits?

I assume this formula gives the max size of packet so it includes all kind of overhead.

Comment: The maximum packet size is determined by the MTU on a link. That is the maximum payload for the layer-2 protocol on the link. The layer-3 packets are the payload of the layer-2 frames.